# On a button click, open new text box in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, rjs

I have a BlogPost resources, where in BlogPost 'show' screen, I want a "new comment" button to be displayed and only on clicking that button I want the new Comment template to be rendered into the same page. I would like to use ajax concept to do this. How do I do this?

NOTE: I have BlogPost and Comment as seperate resources(plural)
Resources I've defined in my routes looks like this:

```
map.resources :blog_posts, :has_many => :comments
```

EDIT: For a better idea, the 'add comment' link just below a question in stackoverflow

Comment: i believe you would put the comments in a  `<div>` specified with an ID and then use something like `jQuery` and `page.insert` in Rails to render your comments view..

Comment: Ok I did try that. But should the 'new_comment' view be a partial?

Comment: just trying to clarify this: Do you want the Comment Box to pop up as a comment window in your application or just want to render the comments view?

Comment: Yes, I want the comment box to pop up as a comment window

Comment: that would be a `jQuery` or javascript function then... Rails has got nothing to do with it.. The only thing that you should remember is to submit the form data to your required method/action via ajax.. I'll post up some links to give you direction..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all you need to do is render the comment box (the HTML markup) on page load but give it a CSS rule to be hidden ( `<div id='comment' style="display:none"> ... comment markup ... </div>` ). Then add a link just above or below that div to show the div and hide the "add comment" link using js (like jquery).

Something like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
function fade_some_stuff(){
   $('#comment_link').click( function(){ $('#comment').fadeIn(); $('#comment_link').fadeOut(); });
}
</script>
<a href="#" id='comment_link'>add comment</a>
<div id='comment' style="display:none;">
 ...
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's the kind of solution I wanted. Exploring more, I was experimenting with the scriptaculus javascript api's. They are so much fun to play with. The above code could also be written as <script type='text/javascript'>
function fade_some_stuff(){
   $('#comment_link').click( function(){ Effect.Appear('comment',{duration:0.5};Effect.Fade('comment_link',{duration:0.5;})return false;}

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need something like this... http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-form

Please go through the documentation provided at the bottom to implement this in your App.

Good Luck!

Comment: Ok. I checked out the link you sent, but its kinda complicated, instead of jQuery, how do I make use of simple rjs? Just like the comment functionality in stackoverflow, for example.